# Swift_TransportException Connection to ssl://mail.diamonexchange.com:465 Timed Out

Tags: laravel, email, webmail

Of recent my laravel app keeps timing out on mail cpanel connection

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mail.******.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=info@*****.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=**********
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=info@*******.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

[Here is screenshot of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YS73w.png)

Comment: Did you try to login your mail addres manually? Is your app and mail server ports open? Which version do you use for Laravel? Also, you are seying 587 but your env shows 465

Comment: I tri3r it works fine ,but from laravel it doesn't. I do not know if the smtp ports are blocked by the  service's firewall